# Google Maps Places API unauthorized error

Tags: python, google-maps, google-api

I'm trying to use the Places API to get a list of restaurants in a city. I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "googlePlacesAPI.py", line 10, in <module>
    radius=20000, types=[types.TYPE_FOOD])
  File "/Users/**me**/Downloads/slimkrazy-python-google-places-d4b7363/googleplaces/__init__.py", line 281, in nearby_search
    lat_lng_str = self._generate_lat_lng_string(lat_lng, location)
  File "/Users/**me**/Downloads/slimkrazy-python-google-places-d4b7363/googleplaces/__init__.py", line 593, in _generate_lat_lng_string
    'lat_lng must be a dict with the keys, \'lat\' and \'lng\'. Cause: %s' % str(e))
ValueError: lat_lng must be a dict with the keys, 'lat' and 'lng'. Cause: Request to URL https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY&address=%7B%27lat%27%3A+%2733.7490%27%2C+%27lng%27%3A+%2784.3880%27%7D failed with response code: REQUEST_DENIED
```

which I believe is the result of my API key not working, despite being enabled in the Google Developer Console. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

ValueError: **lat_lng must be a dict with the keys, 'lat' and 'lng'.**

Cause: 
Request to URL

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&key=**YOUR_API_KEY**&address=%7B%27lat%27%3A+%2733.7490%27%2C+%27lng%27%3A+%2784.3880%27%7D failed with response code: REQUEST_DENIED
```

So, the object must be of a form **{key: value, key: value}** format, and your URL must have a valid **API KEY**. You need to replace that `key=YOUR_API_KEY`with your actual API key.

Comment: Yes, I know I need to put my own API key in. When I do that I have the error.